# ReCaptcha is fine with form, but it signs up without confirmation as well

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a user_registration_controller created following this tutorial : https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-Recaptcha-with-Devise

And I also added `<%= recaptcha_tags %>` to my code (here is my code: https://github.com/prp-e/dakhlokharj). When I run it, it works fine. But there's one problem. User is able to signup even without checking that checkbox. I expected an error.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We need the minimal code and input data to duplicate the problem in the question itself, along with the expected result. Asking us to chase down code off-site slows and discourages help and, when the links break, results in a question that makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

A few months ago I had also faced a lot of problem regarding this then after, below javascript hack successfully work for me :-

Here I added on submit function to prevent unauthenticated signup

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#new_user").on("submit", function (e) {
     return isCaptchaChecked();
    })
    function isCaptchaChecked() {
      if(grecaptcha && grecaptcha.getResponse().length <= 0){
        alert('Please fill the recaptcha.')
        return false;
      }else{
        return true;
      }
    }
  </script>
```

And then in registration controller :-

```
def create
   # then add a check in create method from backend
    unless verify_recaptcha(model: User.new)
      flash[:error] =  "Wrong Captcha!"
      return redirect_to users_registrations_new_user_path
    end
    .......
    .......
    .......
  end
```

This way I solved my problem. Hope this will help you also.